# Error running Linux find command using sed

Tags: linux, sed, find, exec

when i try to run the below;

```
find /tmp/PDraw.pl -type f -exec sed -l 's/PEntries/PEntries2/g'{}\;
```

i get the error "find: missing argument to `-exec'"; I've also tried some posts suggestions to put space between ' and {} and also another between {} and \ but that brings me to another error;

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: extra characters after command
```

my sed version is 4.2.1; This same command ran successfully on another Linux machine. I dont know why its not working now.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a space before {}\;

Comment: ... and the space between `{}` and `\;`

Answer (score 0):

Once you're resolved your `find` issues (see Dorin's answer), you need to sort the `sed` invocation. From my `sed` (v4.2.1):

```
 -l N, --line-length=N
```

which suggests the -l takes a numeric argument. If I take your `sed` invocation and amend with a numeric argument, I don't get the above error. Are you sure this worked on your other machine (are you running the correct `sed`?)